# Injecting higher resolution raster data only in certain areas of an MBTiles file

Tags: gdal, tiles, mbtiles

I have been tasked with combining many raster datasets spread out over a large area into a single MBTiles database. The rasters themselves vary significantly in their resolutions. Some overlap but others are great distances apart. I have a very low resolution raster covering the entire area of interest which is to be used to fill in the spaces between the rasters.

My first attempt was to compose the datasets in a virtual raster (GDAL VRT) using the highest available resolution and then tiling that. While this "worked" it resulted in absolutely enormous file sizes, as the vast majority of the data was oversampled, often to a ridiculous degree.

Does the MBTiles format even support having more zoom levels in some areas than in others?

If so, are there existing tools or workflows for "injecting" high resolution (a.k.a. high zoom level) tiles into a low resolution MBTiles file?

While I have lots of experience working with rasters, I am new to tiling and zoom levels, which leaves me feeling like I don't have the knowledge and terminology to even know what I'm looking for.